# React Native: Undefined is not an object while importing 'localized-strings' object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

Since I'm new to React Native and JS, I've stucked at importing a function from another file and I don't know how to pass it. I'm using library 'localized-strings' from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localized-strings) website. There is my code where I make an object based on this lib:

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'localized-strings';

export default SharedStrings;
let SharedStrings = new LocalizedStrings({
    en: {
        back: 'Back',
        next: 'Next',
        skip: 'Skip',
    },
    fi: {
        back: 'Takaisin',
        next: 'Seuraava',
        skip: 'Hyppiä',
    },
    sw: {
        back: 'Tillbaka',
        next: 'Nästa',
        skip: 'Hoppa',
    },
    de: {
        back: 'Zurück',
        next: 'Nächster',
        skip: 'Überspringen',
    },
})
```

On another .js file, I'm importing it and passing one of these values to the `<Text>` object. Code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import SharedStrings from '../constants/SharedStrings';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{SharedStrings.next}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

After I run it in with Expo CLI on my device, I get this error:
    `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_SharedStrings.default.next')`

What is interesting, when I copy-paste the SharedStrings object to the code I render the `SharedStrings.next` string, it works normally. I don't like this solution and want to keep these translations in separate .js file. 

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So probably the issue is with you are using `SharedStrings` before it's declared.
Try adding the export statement after definition.
For ex

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'localized-strings';

let SharedStrings = new LocalizedStrings({
    en: {
        back: 'Back',
        next: 'Next',
        skip: 'Skip',
    },
    fi: {
        back: 'Takaisin',
        next: 'Seuraava',
        skip: 'Hyppiä',
    },
    sw: {
        back: 'Tillbaka',
        next: 'Nästa',
        skip: 'Hoppa',
    },
    de: {
        back: 'Zurück',
        next: 'Nächster',
        skip: 'Überspringen',
    },
});
export default SharedStrings;
```

or you can do

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'localized-strings';

export default new LocalizedStrings({
    en: {
        back: 'Back',
        next: 'Next',
        skip: 'Skip',
    },
    fi: {
        back: 'Takaisin',
        next: 'Seuraava',
        skip: 'Hyppiä',
    },
    sw: {
        back: 'Tillbaka',
        next: 'Nästa',
        skip: 'Hoppa',
    },
    de: {
        back: 'Zurück',
        next: 'Nächster',
        skip: 'Überspringen',
    },
});
```

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Just tried this on snack this works. I thought the same but wasn't sure if that was the exact problem so tried running on snack.

Comment: Perfect, accept the answer, so that later if someone faces the same type of issue, can refer.
Keep coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not the guy who posted the question. Was just curious and learned something new. Cheers !!